# CMS Editor not working

Tags: html, css, content-management-system, editor, prestashop-1.6

I have created a cms page with a table in it. I am trying to put a border around my table but it does not show the border in the front end. 
I can see the border appear when i edit the page but not on the actual site.

I searched forums and tried to change editor code in js/tinymce.js.inc file but nothing happened.

http://mypresta.eu/en/art/prestashop-16/extended-rich-text-editor.html

This is the html code for table in the editor

```
<table style="height: 670px; width: 429px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="5px" width="429">
```

I can see a 5px thick border in the editor but nothing in the front end. The editor looks so primitive it hardly does anything.

[as you can see border disappears](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/uploads/monthly_03_2015/post-908574-0-85034100-1426116984.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mh, you can also try add border style like this:

```
<table style="height: 670px; width: 429px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border: 5px solid #000000;" width="429">
```

It should help you.